# C - incompatible integer to pointer conversion - Substitution question from CS50

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to convert a single character to the appropriate index character in a 26 letter cipher. I tried to convert the character 'oc' to an integer because the array 'cipher' needs an integer for the index, but I am getting errors which I don't understand.

```
char conversion(char c, string cipher)
{
    // Only change alphabetical characters
    if (isalpha(c) == 0)
    {
        return c;
    }

    char oc;

    // If upper case
    if (isupper(c))
    {
        oc = c - 65;

        int ocint = atoi(oc);

        oc = cipher[ocint];

        oc = oc + 65;

        return oc;
    }
```

I get the errors:

```
error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
        int ocint = atoi(oc);
                         ^~
                         &
/usr/include/stdlib.h:104:30: note: passing argument to parameter '__nptr' here
extern int atoi (const char *__nptr)
```

What does 'take the address with &' mean?

And also '__nptr'?

Comment: `atoi` expects a `char*` but you provide a `char`.

Comment: The error message already tells you. `oc` is of type `char`, whereas atoi takes 'a pointer to char' (`char *`). It expects a string of characters, which is terminated with a NUL-Byte. Hence, atoi is completely unfit for your scenario.

Comment: Actually drop the `atoi` alltogether. `oc = c - 65;` does already what you want. BITW: it should be `oc = c - 'A';` which is the same thing but avoids the magic number 65.

Comment: If I drop the ```atoi``` it does not let me use ```oc``` in the cipher index - it gives me the error "array subscript is of type 'char'"

Comment: @Dan `char conversion(char c, string cipher)` -> `int conversion(char c, string cipher)` and `return oc; ` -> `return (int)oc;`

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you! So you have to cast ```(int)``` to the character to be able to use it as an index

Comment: @Dan You can use a char as array index, but depending on the warning level of the compiler you'll get a warning, but there is nothing wrong with it, provided the array is smaller than 256 elements

Comment: @Dan No, you don't have to cast to `int`! That comment was confused. `char` isn't some magical type, it's just an 8 bit integer. You definitely do not need to cast either way. However, `char` could be a signed type so some compilers might decide to warn because of that.

Answer (score 2):

`atoi` is used for converting whole strings. If you want to convert an individual character A to Z into the corresponding number, then `oc = c - 65;` does that already. Preferably write `oc = c - 'A';`.

So in this specific case you don't even need `atoi`. In the general case, `atoi` should never be used either, because it's an incorrectly designed function without error handling. Always use `strtol` instead.